# Add json objects to array

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

On click of a submit button the data in my textfields and some other data are being converted to a json object like so…

```
    let categoryName = self.categoryTextField.text
    let categoryId = self.categoryID

    let category_json: [String: [String:Any]] = [
        "categoryDetails": [
            "category_name": categoryName,
            "category_id": categoryId
        ]
    ]

    if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: category_json, options: .prettyPrinted),
        let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(str) // `str` gives the json object 
        self.categoryStrToPass = str
    }
```

Now `self.categoryStrToPass` is assigned to another json object and then finally added to a string array like so…

```
    let productID = self.prodID
    let sellingPrice = self.mrpTextField.text
    let categoryJSON = self.categoryStrToPass

    let jsonObject: [String: [String:Any]] = [
        "prodDetails": [
            "product_id": productID,
            "selling_price": sellingPrice,
    “category_json”: categoryJSON

        ]
    ]

    if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted),
        let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(str)
        self.jsonStrToPass = str
        self.jsonStringArray.append(self.jsonStrToPass)
    }
```

Now I’m storing `jsonStringArray` to coredata like so…

```
_product?.setValue(self.jsonStringArray, forKey:
            "productJsonArray") // productJsonArray is an attribute of type Transformable and Custom class type Array<String>
```

And it is being fetched like so...

```
 if let jsonObjArr = result.value(forKey: "productJsonArray") as?
                        Array<NSString> {
                    print(jsonObjArr)

                    }
```

Now on 2 different instances I have submitted the data which means on printing `jsonObjArr` while fetching,it should have 2 different json objects in one array like so..

```
[{
  "prodDetails" : {
    "product_id" : "0",
    "category_json" : "{\n  \"categoryDetails\" : {\n    \"category_id\" : \"0\",\n    \"category_name\" : \"prodCAT\"\n  }\n}",
    "selling_price" : "500",
  }
}

{
  "prodDetails" : {
    "product_id" : "1",
    "category_json" : "{\n  \"categoryDetails\" : {\n    \"category_id\" : \"0\",\n    \"category_name\" : \"CATNEW\"\n  }\n}",
    "selling_price" : "1000",
  }
}]
```

But instead, printing `jsonObjArr` is giving this…in 2 different arrays like so...

```
[{
  "prodDetails" : {
    "product_id" : "0",
    "category_json" : "{\n  \"categoryDetails\" : {\n    \"category_id\" : \"0\",\n    \"category_name\" : \"prodCAT\"\n  }\n}",
    "selling_price" : "500",
  }
}]

[{
  "prodDetails" : {
    "product_id" : "1",
    "category_json" : "{\n  \"categoryDetails\" : {\n    \"category_id\" : \"0\",\n    \"category_name\" : \"CATNEW\"\n  }\n}",
    "selling_price" : "1000",
  }
}]
```

How can I get multiple json objects in one single array...?

Comment: `self.jsonStringArray.append(self.jsonStrToPass)` You are appending two JSON Stringified, it won't work. Instead, append on the "Swift Array form", and then convert to JSON.

Comment: Ok @Larme. It would be grateful on your part if you can suggest how..I've been stuck on this for some time now...:(

Answer (score 0):

you can add objects of type [String: Any] to array like so

```
let firstCategoryName = "first"
let firstCategoryId = 1

let firstCategory = [
    "category_name": firstCategoryName,
    "category_id": firstCategoryId
] as [String : Any]

let secondCategoryName = "second"
let secondCategoryId = 2

var category_json = [[String:Any]]()

category_json.append(firstCategory)

let secondCategory = [
    "category_name": secondCategoryName,
    "category_id": secondCategoryId
    ] as [String : Any]

category_json.append(secondCategory)

print(category_json)
```

then serialize the array

Comment: In my case the first json is put in the second json. In my question,the 1st json is assigned to this variable: `self.categoryStrToPass` and this in turn is assigned to the 2nd json like so...`let categoryJSON = self.categoryStrToPass

    let jsonObject: [String: [String:Any]] = [
        "prodDetails": [
            "product_id": productID,
            "selling_price": sellingPrice,
    “category_json”: categoryJSON

        ]`

Comment: Can your answer be used in that case also...?

Comment: Yes, as the array is defined as [String: Any] so you can add json object

Comment: but you have not converted the data into string..how can we get the output in proper format then..?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.0:**

```
    let firstObj = ["prodDetails": [
                   "product_id": 5,
                   "selling_price": 6,
                   ]]

    let secondObj = ["prodDetails1": [
                    "product_id1": 5,
                    "selling_price1": 6,
                    ]]

    let jsonObject = jsonStringArray.addingObjects(from: [firstObj,secondObj])

    if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted),

        let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(str) //prints array of dictionaries
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Suganya Marlin. But in the end I will have only one json object. It is this json object that is added to the array. Now if I create a new product(it's related to my project & it is when data goes into the json object) the new set of data will append to the array again. Also this doesn't seem to be present `addingObjects(from`..

Comment: u should declare your array as NSArray().Then u will get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164833/discussion-between-bvt-and-suganya-marlin).

Answer (score 0):

`category_json` and `jsonObject` are of the same kind.

What you need to understand:

`(NS)String` <== `String(data:encoding)` or `data(encoding:)` ==> `(NS)Data`

Applied to specific String/Data: JSON:

JSON Stringified <== `String(data:encoding)` or `data(encoding:)` ==> JSON Data

Swift Array/ Swift (and the rest JSON compliant) <== `(NS)JSONSerialization.jsonObject(withData:, options:)` or `(NS)JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:, options:)` ==> JSON Data

You can't append like that the two JSON Stringified, you need to have an array at least at top level.

So, let's connect the dots, in pseudo code (not sure at all that the method name are error free)

```
let currentData = self.jsonStrToPass.data(encoding: .utf8)
let current = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:currentData, options:[]) as [String:[String:Any]]

let finalArray : [[String:[String:Any]]]()
finalArray.append(current)
finalArray.append(jsonObject)

let finalData = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:finalArray, options:[])
let finalString = String(data:finalData, encoding:.utf8)
```

That's for the logic. I didn't do the `if let`, `try`/`catch`, etc.

I'd think it might be better to pass Any (for Swift Array/Dictionary instead of String) between your data to pass. It might be simpler to edit them (append, etc.) instead of String.

Comment: Ok @Larme. Thanks...so will `finalString ` be an array with multiple dictionaries within..?

Comment: `finalString` is the JSONStringified of `finalArray`. so it should be.

Comment: .@Larme after doing what u suggested, I added `finalString ` to a string array and stored it in coredata. And if I have 2 set of data, I am to get 2 dictionaries in the array, But when I retrieve, I get the 1st set of data twice in the 1st array and the 2nd set of data twice in the second array..instead of both different sets of data in 1 array...